# No path, or command history through SSH when logged in to server as someone other than root

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, shell

When I SSH into a server, as anything other than root, it only shows a $ and not the path. It also won't allow me to press the up key and see the command history when I don't SSH in as root. How do I give other users the mentioned options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two steps to accomplish this.

**Step 1)** Make sure your users are using the bash shell.  Look at the entry for each user in /etc/passwd and ensure it ends in /bin/bash.  For example, if you see this:

```
joeuser:x:1234:1234:Joe User:/home/joeuser:/bin/sh
```

then change it to this:

```
joeuser:x:1234:1234:Joe User:/home/joeuser:/bin/bash
```

Using bash should fix the up-arrow problem and will enable the next step.

**Step 2)** If you still don't see a prompt with the current working directory, then tell bash that's what you want.  There are two ways to do this.  Add the following line:

```
export PS1='\w> '
```

to either

1. Each user's `.bash_profile` file; *OR*
2. The system-wide `/etc/profile` file

This line assigns the `PS1` variable, which represents the main shell prompt.  I recommend putting it in `/etc/profile` as this is easier and provides a helpful prompt to all your users.  If a user wants something else for their prompt, they can always edit their own `.bash_profile` file.

Note: if your system has a `/etc/bash.bashrc` then put the line there instead of `/etc/profile`.

Answer (score 1):

My `passwd(5)` man page says this about the last field of an `/etc/passwd` entry, called the “command interpreter”:

> The command interpreter field provides the name of the user's command
>   language interpreter, or the name of the initial program to execute.
>   The login program uses this information to set the value of the $SHELL
>   environmental variable. If this field is empty, it defaults to the
>   value **/bin/sh**.

So, it looks like your options are to:

1. Put your users in the `/etc/passwd` file.
2. Have your users information available by NIS or some other network means.
3. Link `/bin/sh` to some other shell. I don’t recommend this because programs most likely rely on the behaviour of the existing `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds quite odd since—by default—any non-root user should be able to have the basic functionality you describe. That said, this issue does sound familiar. Whenever I setup a user on Ubuntu (Debian) I use [`adduser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man8/adduser.8.html) which works fine; but I have always had issues with [`useradd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man8/useradd.8.html). As it states in the official man page for [`useradd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man8/useradd.8.html):

> `useradd` is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian,
>   administrators should usually use `adduser`(8) instead.

The reason boils down to the fact that `useradd` is ultimately a low-level system binary that requires more commands than just a username to add paths and shell info for a new user. In contrast, `adduser` is a Perl script wrapper for `useradd` that provides a nicer, user-friendly workflow to create a new user to the system without much thought. Just think of `adduser` as a “wizard” setup for `useradd`.

So, if you added a user via `useradd` chances are you missed a config setting in the command-line options. So technically, you did add a user to the system, but not much else in the way of system configuration. In contrast, `adduser` is designed to handle all of the sundry basics.

Knowing that, what I would recommend is you delete any user you have already created like this; of course change `[username]` to the actual username:

```
sudo deluser --remove-home [username]
```

And then recreate that user with `adduser` like this:

```
sudo adduser [username]
```